# How to make sjPlot::tab_model() html table to be numbered in a bookdown document

Tags: r, bookdown, sjplot

I want to add tables from models (besides other tables) in a bookdown document in order to have all of them automatically numbered. When using `knitr::kable()` it works well. But I haven't been able to do it with my first option for model tables `sjPlot::tab_model`, or other functions to create these tables, such as `stargazer::stargazer` and `texreg::htmlreg`

Here's a simple .Rmd example:

````
    ---
    title: "Example"
    output: bookdown::html_document2
    ---

    Bookdown gets numbered tables when using `kable`.

    ```{r tab}
    knitr::kable(head(mtcars),
                   caption = "First table")
    ```

    But I want to make a `tab_model` table to be also automatically numbered in the document

    ```{r lm-tab1}
    reg_mod <- lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)
    sjPlot::tab_model(reg_mod, title = "Second table")
    ```

    Optionally, I would like to be able to do it with other package for creating automatic model 
    tables, such as `stargazer::stargazer`, `texreg::htmlreg` or perhaps other suggestion

    ```{r lm-tab2, results='asis'}
    stargazer::stargazer(reg_mod, type = "html", title = "Third table")
    ```

    ```{r lm-tab3, results='asis'}
    texreg::htmlreg(reg_mod, caption = "Fourth table")
    ```
````

Any idea how to make `tab_model` or any other function for regression models to work with the bookdown numbering?

Comment: See the bookdown documentation here (near the bottom): https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/tables.html

Comment: I've seen it and I'm not able to tell how to resolve the above issue with this information. As far as I know, it's not possible to create markdown output with tab_model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/tables.html), bookdown supports automatically numbering tables generated by other functions if you include a tag like: `(\#tab:my-table-lab)` in the title/caption.

For example, with your `tab_model` table you can do:

```
reg_mod <- lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)
sjPlot::tab_model(reg_mod, title = "(\\#tab:tab-model-table) Second table")
```